# Getting a user variable, setting it's value, and displaying it on another screen

Tags: c#, wpf, expression-blend-4

I am new to WPF, C# and xaml. I'd describe my knowledge as poor, but growing.

I have a very simple application. What I am trying to accomplish is the following:

I have a textbox, and I'm asking the user of the application to enter an email address. I'd like to store that variable somewhere, where I can write it to the screen later. So:
1. Get the email address (User hits a 'Next' button)
2. "Thanks an email will be set to "  "when the utility is finished."

I'm using Blend with SketchFlow. I created a singleton class that allows me to store the variable.

```
namespace Mysillyapplication
{
public class ApplicationParameters
{
    private static ApplicationParameters _instance;
    private string _emailAddress;

    public static ApplicationParameters Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance == null)
            {
                _instance = new ApplicationParameters();
            }
            return _instance;
        }

    }

    public string EmailAddress
    {
        get { return _emailAddress; }
        set
        {
            _emailAddress = value;
        }
    }
}
```

The code for the page that gets the email address:

```
namespace Mysillyapplication
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for BasicParameters.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class BasicParameters : UserControl
{
    public BasicParameters()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string EmailAddress
    {
        get
        {
            return ApplicationParameters.Instance.EmailAddress;
        }
        set
        {
            ApplicationParameters.Instance.EmailAddress = value;
        }
 }
     }
   }
```

In my xaml I have the following lines:

```
<TextBox x:Name="email" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="32,65,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="291"/>
```

AND

```
<i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                <ei:ChangePropertyAction  TargetName="MySillyapplication_BasicParameters_Name" PropertyName="EmailAddress" Value="{Binding Text, ElementName=email}" />
                <pi:NavigateToScreenAction TargetScreen="DBSyncScreens.BeginSync"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
```

AND Finally, I want to display it out on another page:
In that page's CS I have the following lines:

```
public string EmailAddress
    {
        get
        {
            return ApplicationParameters.Instance.EmailAddress;
        }
        set
        {
            ApplicationParameters.Instance.EmailAddress = value;
        }
    }
```

And in the XAML:

```
<TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25" Margin="10,35,0,0" Style="{DynamicResource BasicTextBlock-Sketch}" 
               VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="605" >
        <Run Text="A log of the sync will be sent to "/>
        <Run Text="{Binding EmailAddress, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <Run Text=". Click Next to begin the sync process."/>
    </TextBlock>
```

is wrong and doesn't work.

I could be doing this the wrong way. Anyone have any ideas on how to easily make that user variable email address easy to handle. I feel like what I'm trying to accomplish is very easy, yet I'm having so much difficulty with it.

get a variable, store it, access it on other pages.

Comment: why can't you store the variable in a `Session` variable?

Comment: Could you possible explain a little more on what a session is?

Comment: do you have access to this link [Get answers and Examples to many of your C# Questions Click here](http://www.google.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote about this a bit in my blog post [What is this "DataContext" you speak of?](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2012/07/14/what-is-this-datacontext-you-speak-of/)

To summarize, WPF applications have two layers: the UI layer and the data layer.

The data layer is the `DataContext`, and bindings are used in the UI layer to access data from the data later.

When you write `<TextBox Text="{Binding EmailAddress}" />`, you are telling WPF to look in the data layer (`DataContext`) behind the `TextBox` and bind to the `EmailAddress` property.

The `DataContext` is inherited down the visual tree, so typically you will only see the `DataContext` set once, such as

```
public SomeConstructor()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = ApplicationParameters.Instance;
}
```

It should be noted that you can also specify other binding properties to access values from somewhere other than the current `DataContext`, such as `ElementName` or `Source`.

For example, since you are binding to a `Singleton` property, you could use the following syntax for your binding:

```
Text="{Binding Path=EmailAddress, 
               Source={x:Static my:ApplicationParameters.Instance}}"
```

This would set the source of your binding to your singleton object, so it would bind to `ApplicationParameters.Instance.EmailAddress`

For this to work, you'll also have to specify the "my" namespace, like this:

```
<Window ... xmlns:my="clr-namespace:MyNamespace" />
```

But to make a long story short, the reason why your binding won't work is because the `DataContext` behind your `TextBlock` is not `ApplicationParameters.Instance`, so it finds no `EmailAddress` property to bind to :)

Answer (score 0):

It is because you haven't set your `DataContext` on your second page so it can't find `EmailAddress`.

In your page constructor try adding:

```
DataContext = this;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `BasicParameters` constructor, add the following code:

```
public BasicParameters()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = ApplicationParameters.Instance;
}
```

HTH!